# NoSuchMethodException in JDBI while using it with Lombok

Tags: java, lombok, jdbi

I has immutable class like:

```
@Value
public class MyEntry {
    int id;
    String name;
}
```

[JDBI Developer Guide](https://jdbi.org/#_lombok) states that it should work with `@Value` annotations. At least with `bindBean()` or `@BindBean`.

But when I use `org.jdbi.v3.core.result.ResultBearing#mapToBean` method with `MyEntry.class` it throws `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: no such constructor: my.company.MyEntry.<init>()void/newInvokeSpecial`. Looks like it trying create object with empty constructor and set fields after it. But I want to let my class be immutable. Any thoughts?

UPD:

lombok version: 1.18.20
jdbi version: 3.25.0
jdk: 15 and 16

Failed code:

```
return jdbi.withHandle(
    handle -> handle.createQuery("SELECT * FROM MyTable")
        .mapToBean(MyEntry.class)
        .list()
);
```

Comment: Please, provide `JDBI`/`Lombok` versions and a full example of JDBI call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[JDBI documentation](https://jdbi.org/#_lombok) clearly states:

> Use ConstructorMapper or @RegisterConstructorMapper to map @Value classes.

So your code might look like this (but probably there is no need to register row mapper on each call, it could be done on global level):

```java
return jdbi.withHandle(
    handle -> handle.createQuery("SELECT * FROM MyTable")
        .registerRowMapper(ConstructorMapper.factory(MyEntry.class))
        .mapTo(MyEntry.class)
        .list()
);
```